# Computing the checksum of a file in erlang

Tags: erlang, md5

I am trying to compute the md5 checksum of a large file by using the BIFs that erlang offers:

1. erlang:md5_init()
2. erlang:md5_update()
3. erlang:md5_final()

In the following code:

```
to_md5_large(File) ->
    case file:read_file(File) of
        {ok, <<A:4/binary,B/binary>>} -> md5_helper(B,erlang:md5_init(A));
        {error,Reason} -> exit(Reason)
    end.

md5_helper(<<A:4/binary,B>>,Acc) -> md5_helper(B,erlang:md5_update(Acc,A));
md5_helper(A,Acc) -> 
    B =     erlang:md5_update(Acc,A),
    erlang:md5_final(B).
```

However it seems as if the md5_init() doesn't get recognised. When I compile everything works fine returning the `{ok,module}` however when I run I get an error saying that there is an undefined function md5_init on the line shown above. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

erlang:md5_init has no parameter.

Don't forget that no check is done at compilation about functions defined in other modules.

Comment: Wow. How did I miss that. Mind if I delete?